# MVC Routing Parameter Precedence

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, value-provider

I came across a scenario where I had the default MVC Route setup. Like So.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Then navigating to a url as such

```
domain/controller/action/1234
```

On this page I was then navigating to the same page but with different parameters after a certain event. Like so.

```
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var url = "@Url.Action("action", "controller", new { area = ""})";
    var params = $.param({id: id, vrnsearch: true});
    var fullUrl = url += "?" + params;

    window.location.href = fullUrl;
```

I noticed that the url was still keeping the same id in the url and attaching parameters like so.

```
domain/controller/action/1234?id=4321&vrnsearch=true
```

Now my question is, is there a way to determine a precedence over if it should use the value for id from the url or from the parameter.

I have actually found a work around/fix for my issue by using the below, which removes the id from the url and just uses parameters.

```
@Url.Action("action","controller", new {id = "", area = ""})
```

However was just curious if there is a precedence in parameters vs url routing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query string has nothing at all to do with routing (at least, not unless you customize routing to consider it).

The values that are passed to the `ModelBinder` and to your action method are done so by **Value Providers**. You can control the order of precedence by changing the order in which their corresponding `ValueProviderFactory` is registered in the static `ValueProviderFactories.Factories` property.

[image]

As you can see, the default configuration is to first use the `RouteDataValueProviderFactory` and if it returns no value it will try the `QueryStringValueProviderFactory`. If you change the order of the factories, the order of precedence changes.

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.RemoveAt(3);
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Insert(4, new RouteDataValueProviderFactory());
```