# Parameter in MVC Controller is empty after repost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{appId}/Contract/Create")]
public ActionResult Create(ContractViewModel vm, string appId)
{
    // ...
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return View("Create", vm);
    }
    // ....
}
```

If the controller is called the 1st time `string appId` is perfectly filled with the RouteDictionary value `{appId}`. But if the ModelState is not valid and the client have to post a second time the parameter `string appId` is empty. (The RouteValues still contains the correct `{appId}`, the Form keeps the correct action url.) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does your view looks like ?

Comment: @Shyju ouch, there is a hidden input name="AppId". Apparently the empty input has a higher priority than the route parameters. Solved.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36606015/181087) to control the order of precedence.