# How to access Route Data / Value Provider data in a service in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0

I am attempting to write a [Policy-based Authorization Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies). The business logic of the handler needs to use the record `id` of the current request that is passed in through the default route.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "TaskAdmin", Policy = "RecordOwner")]
public IActionResult Index(int id) // <-- Need this id
{
    // <snip>

    return View();
}
```

### Policy

Here is the class where I need to access the `id` route value.

```
public class RecordOwnerHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RecordOwnerRequirement>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

    public RecordOwnerHandler(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RecordOwnerRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (IsUserAuthorized(context))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        //TODO: Use the following if targeting a version of
        //.NET Framework older than 4.6:
        //      return Task.FromResult(0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private bool IsUserAuthorized(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        //****************************************
        // Need the id here...
        //****************************************

        // Return the result
        return true;
    }
}
```

### Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    // *** Add policy for record owner ***
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("RecordOwner", policy =>
            policy.Requirements.Add(new RecordOwnerRequirement()));
    });

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

    // *** Register record owner handler with the DI container ***
    services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, RecordOwnerHandler>(); 

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

### What I Tried

1. I tried using the `IHttpContextAccessor` as a constructor parameter of `RecordOwnerHandler`, but `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` doesn't seem to contain the `RouteData` of the request.
2. I did several Google searches to see if there was any info about how to do this and came up blank.
3. Then I dug through the source code for both **Routing** and **Model Binding**, but can't seem to find an abstraction that is meant for injecting route values into services.

> I realize I could try to parse this info out of the URL, but I am hoping for a cleaner way to get the value.

So, how can I access **route values** and/or **value provider** data inside of a service in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/41efa409a4188926059001e8b2216d3376b0b705/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.Test/Internal/AttributeRouteTest.cs#L56) help?

Comment: @Mike - Nope. However, I was able to work it out by searching the repo for "accessor" to see if there was one that suited my needs.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Route values can be accessed by using the [`ActionContextAccessor` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.actioncontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-2.0).

### DI Registration

```
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

### Usage

```
public class RecordOwnerHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RecordOwnerRequirement>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;
    private readonly IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor;

    public RecordOwnerHandler(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
        this.actionContextAccessor = actionContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(actionContextAccessor));
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RecordOwnerRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (IsUserAuthorized(context))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        //TODO: Use the following if targeting a version of
        //.NET Framework older than 4.6:
        //      return Task.FromResult(0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private bool IsUserAuthorized(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        // Now the id route value can be accessed directly...
        var id = this.actionContextAccessor.ActionContext.RouteData.Values["id"];

        // Use the dbContext to compare the id against the database...

        // Return the result
        return true;
    }
}
```

> **NOTE:** I would still like to find out a way to access the value providers to do this, so it wouldn't matter if the parameter is passed through route values, query string, form values, etc.

Comment: From my understanding of the RouteData values. They are aggregated from the values into the RouteValueDictionary. So I am a little confused about the footnote in your answer.

Comment: In MVC 5, the values that are provided to the `ModelBinder` and to the action method parameters are read through a collection of **[Value Providers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36606015)** that read the data from query string, route values, form values and various other places in the context. I can see by analyzing the source that it is still done in much the same way in ASP.NET Core, however I haven't found a way to get access to them to read the values they provide.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: I believe you can and should register it as a singleton like `services.AddTransient<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();` See https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/test/WebSites/VersioningWebSite/Startup.cs for an example.

Comment: This does nothing in .NET 5.0.

Answer (score 7):

For future reference, starting .NET Core 5.0, the HttpContext is now passed instead, so you can do:

```
if (context.Resource is HttpContext httpContext)
{
   var value = httpContext.GetRouteValue("key");
}
```

See this for reference [[AspNetCore] Authorization resource in endpoint routing will now be HttpContext](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/19034)

Comment: Accepted answer didn't work for me. ActionContext was always null. This one did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about .NET Core 2.0, but in 3.0 you can access route values with the help of `IHttpContextAccessor`, with a service implementation that will be provided automatically for you by the framework (so no need to register anything).

```cs
public class RecordOwnerHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RecordOwnerRequirement>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public RecordOwnerHandler(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RecordOwnerRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (IsUserAuthorized(context))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        //TODO: Use the following if targeting a version of
        //.NET Framework older than 4.6:
        //      return Task.FromResult(0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private bool IsUserAuthorized(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        if (!_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues.TryGetValue("id", out var id))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // TODO Whatever logic you need to perform with the id

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same use case and tried accessing the route value through the endpoint metadata in the AuthorizationHandler as recommended in the [Access MVC request context in handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0#access-mvc-request-context-in-handlers) section from the ASP.NET Core 5 Security docs:

```
if (!(context.Resource is Endpoint endpoint)) throw new InvalidOperationException("endpoint routing required");
var id = endpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>()?.RouteValues["id"];
```

But the `context.Resource` was of type `DefaultHttpContext`, so instead I had to do this:

```
public class RecordOwnerHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RecordOwnerRequirement>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

    public RecordOwnerHandler(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RecordOwnerRequirement requirement) {
        if (IsUserAuthorized(context))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        //TODO: Use the following if targeting a version of
        //.NET Framework older than 4.6:
        //      return Task.FromResult(0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private bool IsUserAuthorized(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        //****************************************
        // Need the id here...
        //****************************************
        if (!(context.Resource is DefaultHttpContext httpContext)) throw new InvalidOperationException("DefaultHttpContext expected");
        var id = httpContext.Request.RouteValues["id"];    

        // Return the result
        return true;
    }
}
```