# Route id not being picked up in Asp.Net Core MVC controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Given the following HTML:

```
 <li>
     <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Products" asp-route-id="0">
        <i class="si si-drop"></i>
        <span class="sidebar-mini-hide">EnerBurn</span>
      </a>
  </li>
```

produces this URL:

> https://localhost:44356/Product/Products/0

But in this controller action, the selected variable is always 0.
Why isn't the controller action picking up the id from the URL route?
This is the `HttpGet` controller action:

```
public IActionResult Products(int selected)
{
    var pivm = new ProductInfoViewModel {SelectedId = selected};
    pivm= UpdateModelFromSelectedId(pivm);
    return View(pivm);
}
```

Comment: have you tried naming your action parameter `id`

Comment: or use asp-route-selected="0" instead of asp-route-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current action definition, MVC tries to populate the `selected` value from query params (this is by default) and fails as you pass it as part of URL.

And so as you want this to be part of URL, you need to specify this explicitly as part of routing:

- Via route attribute:

  ```
  [Route("Product/Products/{selected}")]
  public IActionResult Products(int selected)
  ```
- Or if you use the convention routing

  ```
  routes.MapRoute("products", {controller=Product}/{action=Products}/{selected?}");
  ```

Comment: @Set...and if I wanted the attribute to be a string value instead of an int, how would I go about that?

Comment: @dinotom if you are asking about constraint setup, then check [Route Constraint Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing#route-constraint-reference). If you just want to change a parameter type - just modify your method's argument to `string selected`

Comment: This is completely incorrect. Routes ignore query string parameters. Query string values are passed into action methods by [Value Providers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36606015). If you pass the URL `/product/products?selected=123` it will not match this attribute route at all.

Comment: @NightOwl888 just reread question - he wants to have a URL like `/product/products/selected`

Comment: Ok, I still stand by the fact that query params are not picked up by routes at all unless you customize routing to consider them. You should remove that part from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code and put `id` instead of `selected`:

```
public IActionResult Products(int id)
{
    var pivm = new ProductInfoViewModel {SelectedId = id};
    pivm= UpdateModelFromSelectedId(pivm);
    return View(pivm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use "int selected"? It requires custom routing.

Use "string id" and MVC will handle it for you by default.
If you need the input parameter to be an int, then convert it to an int (in try catch?).

```
//in: id represents selected index
public IActionResult Products(string id)
{
int selected = Convert.ToUInt32(id);
//do work....
}
```