# In MVC5, how can I use a "folder" as parameter for Index?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In MVC5, how can I use a "folder" as parameter for Index?

I have this controller method:

```
public class HookController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("hook/{pattern}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string pattern)
    {      
    }
}
```

I can currently call it like this:  `/hook/?pattern=testpattern`
..but I'd like `pattern` to be populated when I call `/hook/testpattern` as a folder/path.

I thought I could do it with `[Route("hook/{pattern}")]`  but that has no effect and I just get 404 not found.

Comment: *I can currently call it like this:  `/hook/?pattern=testpattern`* - For the record, that URL does not match `[Route("hook/{pattern}")]`. It is probably matching your default route instead. Routing *ignores* query string parameters, but they end up being passed into the model binder and action method parameters by [value providers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36606015).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.  MVC Routing Attributes weren't enabled as I was missing this line:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

This goes in `RegisterRoutes()` (RouteConfig.cs) before the default route.